# PHP Sessions... (Must destroy)

Tags: php, session, destroy

I want to create a PHP session for my website...

I want that, once anybody starts a session, it could only see/visit specific pages of the website... And when he/she clicks some other link (i don't want him to visit), the session must destroy...

And he must have to enter username/password the next time he/she want to start a session...

```
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("school", $con);

    $un=$_POST["username"];
    $pass=$_POST["password"];

    $query= "SELECT username FROM login where username= '".$un."' AND  password = '".$pass."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($rows > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']=$data['username'];
        header("location: ../Index3.html");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: ../Pages/Admin_panel.html");
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Unable to Sign In!");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no question here

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injections

Comment: You must be a control freak. I would hate to be in a relationship with you.

Comment: @JohnConde How do you know he doesn't use magic_quotes?

Comment: That would be even worse

Comment: No that wouldn't. That protects anyone from reading / writing files on the file system for the cost of a bit of performance, which is actually a good thing if you do not know about handling user inputs properly.

Comment: @Loïc magic_quotes is disabled by default in 5.3 and removed in 5.4. To enable that setting he should know what it does or make some research. At that point he would discovered about proper way to do handle user input. So my dear Watson, my 50 cents goes to "*he does not have magic_quotes enabled*". Even is running older version of php and that setting is enabled, that is not the proper way to handle untrusted data in a SQL context. As a side note: please stop encouraging PHP newcomers to bad practices.

Comment: That is not THE proper way, right.
But, Sherlock, let me tell you that magic_quotes were SAFE ENOUGH. Removing them will lead to several server rapes. And of course it's a good thing to learn about escaping and casting ints, but there will be more and more zombies servers since they have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, there :

```
  header("location: ../Pages/Admin_panel.html");
  ?>
  <script>
  alert("Unable to Sign In!");
  </script>
  <?php
```

Everything following the `header()` relocation won't get executed.

Instead you can use :

```
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("Unable to Sign In!");
    window.location.replace('/Pages/Admin_panel.html')
    </script>
    <?php die();
}
```

Then in your other pages which require rights, add the following code :

```
<?php

if($_SESSION['user_rights'] != 'admin'){ //whatever rights he would need to access this page
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../Pages/login.html"); //your login page.
}
?>
```

Comment: Ohh well......
Thankyou soooooooo very much "LOIC" bro...
I appreciate your brief answer... (y)

Comment: If you really do, accept this as an answer and reward me for my help ;-)

Comment: Left of the post there is a "v" symbol, just click on it. Thanks :)

Comment: DONE... Have fun... :D